# How to set the filename for a downloadable file in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i want to rename the a file that can be downloaded from the website.

This is how i populate the response.

```
return response()->view('ordersxml.order-template',compact('order','debtor','today'))->header('Content-Type','text/xml')->header('Content-disposition','attachment')->header('filename','test');
```

The `->header('filename','test');`

Is not working.
What am i doing wrong?

THanks in advance

Comment: There's no header `filename`

Comment: are you download image ?

Answer (score 9):

Of course, you can add header `filename`, but it won't work, because proper header for download is:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"
```

So, you code should be:

```
return response()
     ->view('ordersxml.order-template',compact('order','debtor','today'))
     ->header('Content-Type','text/xml')
     ->header('Content-disposition','attachment; filename="test"'));
```